# Nest 0.12 is DeleteByQueryRaw deprecated?

Tags: nest

I have been using DeleteByQueryRaw to successfully delete index objects but now I have updated to 0.12 it is missing. Is there a replacement 'raw' method of calling ES to delete in the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the [Delete By Query](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/delete-by-query.html) method that is part of 0.12, perhaps coupled with the `DeleteByQueryParameters` object to achieve the same results of using the previous DeleteByQueryRaw?

**Update:**

Appears that the forthcoming Elasticsearch.Net, which the next version of NEST will be built upon, will support/expose the entire ES API.

> Elasticsearch.Net maps all the Elasticsearch API endpoints to methods.

See [Elasticsearch.Net Building Requests](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/building-requests.html) for more details.

So based on this, you should be able to still do a 'raw' delete request using Elasticsearch.Net.

Comment: Yes, I can do this IDeleteResponse response = Es.ElasticClient.DeleteByQuery(f => f.Term("taskID", 3)); But wanted to know if there was a replacement